# How to make css grid elements' width be the same as height when scrolling?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, tailwind-css

I want to generate a 51x51 grid of Square components. If I zoom, the overflow allows me to scroll to the rest of the content. However, the components' height and width are never equal, and when I scroll up, the height gets updated nicely, however width stays the same, with the 'O' placeholders overflowing each other - if their widths adjusted, the problem wouldn't exist anymore and I could just scroll vertically. Also, when I scroll, the gap between elements constantly changes.

Consider these react components with tailwindcss:

BoardContainer.tsx

```
const BoardContainer: FC = () => {
    const boardSquares: ReactElement[] = [];
    for (let i : number = 0; i < 2601; i++) {
        boardSquares.push(<Square key={i} i={i}/>);
    }

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen w-screen ">
      <div className="board-container h-[92.5%] w-[60%]">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-51 grid-rows-51 overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-scroll">
          {boardSquares}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Square.tsx:

```
const Square = ({i} : {i: number}) => {
    return (
        <div className={"flex justify-center border border-gray-200"}>
            {'O'}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Square;
```

[image: 100%]
100% zoom

[image: 220%]
220% zoom

I tried to adjust the parameters, but I never get the right result.

Comment: not a react question nor to solve with JS. Simply use `aspect-ratio: 1;` in CSS. Instead of using flexbox use a real CSS-Grid!